# How do I replace entire HTML tags with their alt text equivalent , using simpleDOMparser in PHP?

Tags: php, replace, simple-html-dom, html

Here's an example:

I have a DOM object, `$content` created from this div :

```
<div class="content">&quot;test&quot; <!-- m -->
    <a class="postlink" href="http://imaginethisisareallylongurl.com">http://imagin...longurl.com</a><!-- m -->
    <img src="./images/smilies/icon_e_biggrin.gif" alt=":D" title="Very Happy" /> &quot;test&quot;
    <img src="./images/smilies/icon_e_sad.gif" alt=":(" title="Sad" /> sl
    <img src="./images/smilies/icon_e_biggrin.gif" alt=":D" title="Very Happy" />
    <img src="./images/smilies/icon_e_sad.gif" alt=":(" title="Sad" /> ok
</div>
```

And I want to get this output:

```
"test" http://imaginethisisareallylongurl.com :D :( sl :D :( ok
```

Image tags within the div are replaced by their alt attributes and URLs are replaced by their full `href` attributes.

How can I do this?

Edit :

Something like this:

```
    foreach($content->find('a[class=postlink]') as $postlink)
    {
        $postlink->outertext = $postlink->href;

    }
```

does not work. How can I reference this specific link in the `$contents->innertext` so that I can modify it?

Comment: open the text as a dom document, then parse the inner text.

Comment: Also, [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried?)

Comment: @ColeJohnson you forgot the .com, so that link is invalid

Answer (score 0):

I should have read the documentation more carefully. You can customize the parsing behaviour like so :

```
$html->set_callback('custom_parse');
```

where `$html` is your original DOMDocument.

```
function custom_parse($element)
{
    if (isset($element->class)){
        if($element->class=='postlink'){
            $element->outertext = $element->href;
        }
    } 

    if (isset($element->innertext)){   
        $element->innertext = str_replace('<!-- m -->', '', $element->innertext);
    }

    if (isset($element->outertext)){   
        if ($element->tag=='img' and isset($element->alt)){
            $element->outertext = $element->alt;
        }
    }

}
```

then on my content object I can call this:

```
function parse_content($content)
{
    $content = $content->innertext;
    $content = strip_tags($content);
    $content = html_entity_decode($content);
    return $content;
}
```

No idea if this is the "right" way to do it, but it returns the desired output.